# Enablement of retarget action in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a popup menu and a main menu item to enable when a variable got selected.I have implemented the particular enable action for popup menu. But I was unable to do it in menu item since I have used ActionSet.
So how do I handle enable disable of menu item.

style="push"
               tooltip="%ConvertConstantsToEnumToolTip">

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<enablement>`. The link below might help

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsptopic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_actionSets.html